# Dynamic fields depending of previous fields with WTForms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am making a form using WTForms. For the moment, I have this:

```
class UploadForm(flask_wtf.Form):
    fichier = wtforms.fields.FileField(u'Fichier')
    description = wtforms.fields.TextAreaField(u'Description')
    year = wtforms.fields.SelectField(u'Année', choices=[('1A','1A'),('2A','2A')])
    subject = wtforms.fields.SelectField(u'Matière', choices=app.config['SUBJECTS'])
    submit = wtforms.fields.SubmitField(u'Envoyer')
```

With `SUBJECTS = [('Sub1','Sub1'), ('Sub2','Sub2')]` and this template:

```
{% block content %}
  <h2>Form</h2>
  <form action="{{ url_for('get') }}" method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

    {{ form.fichier.label }}
    {{ form.fichier }}

    {{ form.description.label }}
    {{ form.description }}

    {{ form.year.label }}
    {{ form.year }}

    {{ form.subject.label }}
    {{ form.subject }}

    {{ form.submit }}
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

But the subjects are not the same for all the years, so I’d like to make the list for the subject field dynamic, in order to propose only the subjects corresponding with the selected year. Any idea how I can do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can customize the choices value by assignment post-construction in your view:

```
def view():
    form = UploadForm(request.form, ...)
    if form.year.data == '1A':
        form.subject.choices = SUBJECTS_1A
    else:
        form.subject.choices = SUBJECTS_2A

    if request.form and form.validate():
       [...]
```

Of course, it's even more pythonic to use dicts as a lookup mapping.

```
SUBJECTS_BY_YEAR = {
    '1A': [('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')],
    '2A': [...],
}

def view():
    form = UploadForm(request.form)
    form.subject.choices = SUBJECTS_BY_YEAR.get(form.year.data) or []
```

As long as the choices are set before `validate()` is called, then you're good to go.

For reference see [SelectField from Dynamic Choices](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.5/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField)  in the WTForms docs.