# how to create 2 select fields with dependency in each other wtf_forms flask

Tags: python, forms, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

```
class UpForm(FlaskForm):
    """Uploading form."""
    user_file = FileField('please upload a file',validators=[FileRequired()])
    category_1 = SelectField("main category")
    category_2 = SelectField("secondery category")
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

this is my form it is a form for uploading files and managing them using the categories that I get from the users

- I am new to using flask and wtf forms

first I want to know where do i write the options and how do write them for each select field?

and also I want to create dependency between the two categories so that each answer in one will give me a set of options in the second
for example:
cat_1->action movies ->  cat_2->action1,action2,action3
cat_1->drama movies ->  cat_2->drama1,drama2,drama3

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I personally didn't find quite straightforward solution to this in flask. In my project I'm using method from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2dJuNwlIH0&list=LL&index=1) tutorial.

1. create route which return jsonify
2. create javascript onchange event which will populate second select field

All you need is in linked video.

Comment: is there a way to do this without javascript?

Comment: If yes, I don't know it. But I also fight a lot with this and the video I post was I think the easiest solution. If you find some better, don't hessitate to post it here ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Options can be added to a select field using this syntax

   `category = SelectField(choices=[("action", "action movies"), ("drama", 'drama movies')])`
2. As for the dependency, I would say, have separate dropdowns when user selects from first dropdown then show and hide dependent dropdowns based on the selection using javascript or Jquery

   actionMovies= SelectField(choices=[("action1", "action1"), ("action2", 'action2'), ("action3", 'action3')])

   dramaMovies= SelectField(choices=[("drama1", "drama1"), ("drama2", 'drama2'), ("drama3", 'drama3)])

[Here is a working example of the jquery to display dependent dropdown](https://codepen.io/nik8singh/pen/XWZpQqB)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737255/dynamic-fields-depending-of-previous-fields-with-wtforms i saw the solution in this post but the solution only works post sumiting the form, anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: @pacmarko What do you mean by "Post submitting the form" ?

Comment: after I choose one option it does not change by what i pick unless I am submiting the form or refresh the page

Comment: Look at the example I gave. It doesn't need refreshing or submitting form until you are sending all the dropdowns in the api request and hiding and showing them based on the selected.